# I am trying to display text over image on more info click

Tags: html, forms, razor

I am trying to display text over image on more info click and hide text from image on hide info button click.

I am developing website in razor. I am trying to display text over image on more info click and hide text from image on hide info button click.

```
<style>
    .portfolioImage {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .portfolioImage .footerBar {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;          
        left: 0;
        margin-top: -200px;
        border-radius: 5px;       
    }

    .portfolioImage:hover .footerBar {
        margin-top: 0px;
        background-color: #ffb268;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .footerBar {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
        transition: all 0.7s ease;
    }    
</style>

<div class="thumbnail" style="padding:0px;height:200px">
    <div class="portfolioImage" id="portfolioImage@(i)">
        <div class="footerBar" id="footerBar@(i)">
            <table class="table rate-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Passenger Fare</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="image_frame@(i)" class="image_frame">
            <img alt="100%x200" data-src="@(Url.Content("~/Images/van/"+vanImg+".png"))" src="@(Url.Content("~/Images/van/" + vanImg + ".png"))" data-holder-rendered="true" style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>                              
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a id="btncollapseShow@(i)" name="btncollapse@(i)" onclick="ShowHideRates('@(i)','show')" style="color:#4285f4;font-size:small;cursor:pointer;" class="btnExpand" title="@Global.Translate("More info")">  &#43; </a>
        <a id="btncollapseHide@(i)" name="btncollapse@(i)" onclick="ShowHideRates('@(i)','hide')" style="color:#4285f4;font-size:small;cursor:pointer;display:none;" class="btnExpand" title="@Global.Translate("Hide info")">  &#8211; </a>
    </div>

function ShowHideRates(_cellindex, _showHide) {        
    var _image_frame = "#image_frame" + _cellindex;
    var btncollapseShow = "#btncollapseShow" + _cellindex;
    var btncollapseHide = "#btncollapseHide" + _cellindex;

    if (_showHide == "show") {
        $(btncollapseShow).css({ "display": "none" });
        $(btncollapseHide).css({ "display": "block" });
        // $(_image_frame).addClass("portfolioImage footerBar").css('margin-top','+200');         
    } else {
        $(btncollapseShow).css({ "display": "block" });
        $(btncollapseHide).css({ "display": "none" });
        // $(_image_frame).removeClass("footerBar");    
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand your question

Comment: i have one image div and table div.  table div contains header and data. onclick of header  i want to display  table data on image div

Comment: I would suggest, not to use img tag and use normal DIV and set image in background of this DIV. add one span with Text to that DIV and show hide as you need. Do you need code for it?

Comment: yes i need code